# Leer una tabla join en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como puedo leer (find, take) una tabla join creada a partir de las tabla contacto y grupo, en la migración se creo la tabla join **GrupoContacto**, pero no la veo en el modelo.

Adjunto migración de tabla contacto, grupo y grupocontacto.

```
class CreateContactos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :contactos do |t|
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :numero
      t.string :archivo, default: "** cargado en linea **"

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

...

```
class CreateGrupos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :grupos do |t|
      t.string :nombre

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

...

```
class CreateJoinTableGrupoContacto < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :grupos, :contactos do |t|
      # t.index [:grupo_id, :contacto_id]
      # t.index [:contacto_id, :grupo_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Mis versiones de ruby y RoR son respectivamente:

ruby -v

**ruby 2.3.3p222** (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

rails -v

**Rails 5.1.3**

para clonarlo y ejecutarlo:

git clone https://github.com/rrg1459/ContactosYGrupos.git

cd ContactosYGrupos

rails db:migrate

rails s

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de acciones ejecutarás sobre la tabla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes generar tu el modelo, simplemente crea el archivo *app/models/grupos_contacto.rb*:

```
class GruposContacto < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Y lo podrás leer utilizando el método `find_by`<sup>1</sup> o `where`, por ejemplo:

```
GruposContacto.find_by(grupo_id: 1)
GruposContacto.where(grupo_id: 1)
```

La diferencia es que `find_by` regresa el primer registro que encuentra con la condición dada, mientras que `where` regresa todos lo que cumplan con dicha condición.

Ambos métodos aceptan más de un atributo, por lo que podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
GruposContacto.find_by(grupo_id: 1, contacto_id: 2)
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *No podrás utilizar `find` ya que no tiene columna `id`.*</sup>